# Fórmula de Baskara em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, equações

Estou estudando Python e tentei montar a formula de Baskara, porém os resultados estão saindo diferente do esperado! Alguém pode me ajudar ? Não sei onde está errado!

```
 import math

    a = int(input ("Qual o valor de a: " ))
    b = int(input ("Qual o valor de b: " ))
    c = int(input ("Qual o valor de c: " ))

    Delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
    
    raiz = ((-1*b) + math.sqrt(Delta))//2*a
    
    raiz2 = ((-1*b)- math.sqrt(Delta))//2*a
    
    if Delta == 0:
         print ("O valor da raiz é:" + str(raiz) )

    if Delta>0:
         print ("O valor das raizes é: " + str(raiz) + " e " + str(raiz2) )

    if Delta<0:
         print ("Essa equação não possui raizes reais" )
```

Comment: Qual entrada produz resultados errados?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Acabei fuçando um pouquinho e descobri. Na linha que eu indico a raiz 1 e 2 estava faltando o (2*a). Desse jeito, a equação estava "quebrada".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
'''
Se voce calcular o "Delta" antes, podera evitar erros.
'''

import math

# Coeficientes
a = int(input ("Qual o valor de a: " ))
b = int(input ("Qual o valor de b: " ))
c = int(input ("Qual o valor de c: " ))

# Funcção
def eq_segundo_grau(a, b, c):

    Delta = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if Delta == 0:
        raiz = ((-1*b) + math.sqrt(Delta))/2*a
        raiz2 = ((-1*b)- math.sqrt(Delta))/2*a
        print ("O valor da raiz é:" + str(raiz) )

    elif Delta>0:
        raiz = ((-1*b) + math.sqrt(Delta))/2*a
        raiz2 = ((-1*b)- math.sqrt(Delta))/2*a
        print ("O valor das raizes é: " + str(raiz) + " e " + str(raiz2) )

    else:
        print ("Essa equação não possui raizes reais" )

# Chamada da função
eq_segundo_grau(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Faltou o parênteses no `2 * a`. Teste, por exemplo, `print(10 / 2 * 3)` e `print(10 / (2 * 3))` (o primeiro dá 15, porque primeiro divide por 2 e multiplica o resultado por 3; o segundo dá 1.666666 porque primeiro multiplica, e depois divide pelo resultado da divisão). E se delta é zero, não precisa calcular duas raízes (vc só imprime a primeira aliás, pra que calculou a segunda então? elas são iguais). Aliás, a raiz de zero é zero, é desnecessário calcular a raiz nesse caso: https://ideone.com/loTLV4